# Dynamic List View Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I'm trying to make a dynamic list view of books based on a search query by title, author, or ISBN.

I can display one item, but for whatever reason, I can't see any other items that match the search query.

**Main method**

```
    // Set up search array
    int i = 0;
    String searchEntries[] = InventoryAdapter.getTitleAndAuthorByISBN(isbn);
    searchArray.add(new InventoryItem(searchQuery, searchEntries));


    // add data in custom adapter
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list, searchArray);
    ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InventoryItem> {
   Context context;
   int layoutResourceId;
   LinearLayout linearMain;
   ArrayList<InventoryItem> data = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

   public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                 ArrayList<InventoryItem> data) {
          super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
          this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
          this.context = context;
          this.data = data;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View row = convertView;

          if (row == null) {
                 LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                 row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                 linearMain = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.lineraMain);

                 InventoryItem myItem = data.get(position);
                 for (int j = 0; j < myItem.getDetails().length; j++) {
                       TextView label = new TextView(context);
                       label.setText(myItem.details[j]);
                       linearMain.addView(label);
                 }
          }

          return row;

   }

}
```

**InventoryItem**

```
public class InventoryItem {

   public String query;
   public String details[];

   public InventoryItem(String query, String[] details) {
          super();
          this.query = query;
          this.details = details;
   }
   public String getQuery() {
          return query;
   }
   public void setQuery(String query) {
          this.query = query;
   }
   public String[] getDetails() {
          return details;
   }
   public void setDetails(String[] details) {
          this.details = details;
   }

}
```

**list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/lineraMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main method xml**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="95"
            android:orientation="vertical">


             <ScrollView  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:overScrollMode="always" 
                    android:isScrollContainer="true" 
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
                    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">

                 <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                         <ListView
                              android:id="@+id/list"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                         </ListView>    

                </LinearLayout>

             </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. Bad Design not recommended.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Quoting docs

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.

Also change `getView`to

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View row = convertView;

      if (row == null) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
             linearMain = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.lineraMain);
             }

             InventoryItem myItem = data.get(position);
             TextView label = new TextView(context);
             label.setText(myItem.details[positon]);
             linearMain.addView(label);

      return row;

   }
```

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/lineraMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Then in `getView`

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

      if ( convertView== null) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
             convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
             holder = ViewHolder();
             holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv); 
             convertView.setTag(holder);  
       }
       else
       {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
       } 

             InventoryItem myItem = data.get(position);
             holder.tv.setText(myItem.details[positon]);


      return convertView;

   }

   static class ViewHolder
   {
         TextView tv;
   }
```

Comment: The main difference in your getView edit is that you took out the for loop, but if I take out the for loop, what do I put in label.setText(myItem.details[j]); - there is no "j" without that for loop?

Comment: @user3152800 yes it is not necessary. that is why. you can use `position`

Comment: @user3152800 and a big not to listview in scrollview. remove scrollview

Comment: The original edits worked for me. Thanks.
The new edit suggestion seems to have problems for me. static class ' ViewHolder
   {
         TextView tv;
   } '
There is no constructor so I'm getting errors because there is no ViewHolder type.

Comment: @user3152800 you need to have a textview in the layout first. that is just a view holder class for smooth scrolling and preformance. It is not wrong.http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: `holder.tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);` gives me an error "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type CustomAdapter" because the adapter never get the context and I cannot extend Activity since I already extend ArrayList. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: @user3152800 it should be holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv)